# Bootstrap - How to make two divs start off side by side then stack both separately with text left aligned on narrow viewports?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to stack two divs (initially side by side with left aligned, right aligned text respectively in each div to start off with).

When I shrink the viewport smaller past the size for each div, I want to stack both divs with text aligned left (same alignment as each other in each div).

How can I achieve this effect?

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
     <div class="row text">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <span class="label">Email us:</span><a class="active normal" href="mailto:email@server.com">email@server.com</a>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
             <span class="label">Call us:</span><a class="active normal">1-888-888-8888</a>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS - Sass**

```
div.footer
    padding-top: 15px
    padding-left: 40px
    background: #eeeeee
    height: 60px

div.footer div.left
    padding-left: 15px

div.footer div.right
    margin-right: 40px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use media queries and make the display: block  and width: 100%  (from inline-block and width 50% initially) when the viewport became too small.  I also modified the html div classes to include col-sm-6 and col-md6 for each of side by side divs.

**CSS**

```
div.footer
    display: block
    padding-top: 15px
    padding-bottom: 15px
    padding-left: 40px
    background: #eeeeee none
    height: auto

div.footer div.left
    padding-left: 15px

div.justify
    width: 100%

div.justify div 
    width: 50%
    display: inline-block

div.row.justify div:last-child
    text-align: right !important

@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
    div.justify div 
        display: block
        width: 100%
    div.row.justify div:last-child
        text-align: left !important
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
               <div class="row justify text">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <span class="label">Email us:</span><a class="active normal" href="mailto:email@server.com">email@server.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <span class="label">Call us:</span><a class="active normal">1-888-888-8888</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```